# create table with different queries mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to create a table with the name of the WORKER, the total Square meteres he built and the total cost he was paid.

i have 2 tables

tbl_orden and tbl_costos

the obrero is the foreign key in tbl_costos

this is the query im trying:

```
SELECT a.obrero AS MAESTRO, ROUND(SUM(metros_c),2) AS METROS, SUM(b.costo_semanal)
FROM tbl_orden as a, tbl_costos as b GROUP BY a.obrero
```

Im trying the above query but i dont get the proper result. The SUM of metros_c is not correct neither the sum of the costo_semanal

tbl_order

- id (int) primary key
- name_obra (varchar)
- num_fab (int)
- dated (date)
- type (varchar)
- obrero (varchar)
- metros_c (float)
- comment (varchar)

tbl_costos:

- id (int ) primary key
- costo_semanal (float)
- obrero (foreign key from tbl_order)
- fechai (date)
- fechaf (date)

I want this query results:

```
 SELECT obrero AS Maestro, ROUND(SUM(metros_c),2) AS Metros_Cuadrados, ROUND(SUM(metros_c)/MONTH(CURDATE()),2) as Promedio_Mensual, ROUND(SUM(metros_c)/WEEK(CURDATE()),2) as Promedio_Semanal FROM `tbl_orden`
          WHERE dated BETWEEN '01/01/2015' AND '01/01/2016' GROUP BY obrero ORDER BY metros_c asc
```

and this query results in other column of the above table:

```
SELECT SUM(costo_semanal) from tbl_costos GROUP BY obrero
```

with the first query i get 4 columns and with the 2nd i get 1. i want to have a result table with the 5 columns

Comment: Please share your tables' structure, some sample data, and the expected result for this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put each into an inline view and then join them to do this:

```
select x.*,
       y.sum_costo_semanal
  from (select obrero as maestro,
               round(sum(metros_c), 2) as metros_cuadrados,
               round(sum(metros_c) / month(curdate()), 2) as promedio_mensual,
               round(sum(metros_c) / week(curdate()), 2) as promedio_semanal
          from tbl_orden
         where dated between '01/01/2015' and '01/01/2016'
         group by obrero) x
  join (select obrero,
               sum(costo_semanal) as sum_costo_semanal
          from tbl_costos
         group by obrero) y
    on x.obrero = y.obrero
```

Comment: WOAH, had to change little things, but that answer was right! thanks!

Comment: SO what if i wantet to add more columns to Y table? but not all?? because i cant do y.sum_costo_semanal, y.whatever, y.other

Comment: You just have to be sensitive to how adding columns affects the sums as whatever additional columns you select must also be added to the group by clause, which will change the amounts accordingly. If you want the sum for each `obrero` and not the sum for that and whatever other columns you're referring to, you'll have to use a third inline view and perhaps name it Z. This all depends on how you want to group for that sum in Y